# Amazon advertisement api asins report type returning empty list

Tags: python, amazon-advertising-api

I am trying to get the asins report from amazon advertising api.
The header and json for creation of the report as follows,

```
headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_code}",
        "Amazon-Advertising-API-ClientId": "client_id",
        "Amazon-Advertising-API-Scope": "Profile_id"
    }
```

```
asins_json_data = {
    "reportDate": "20220227",
    "campaignType": "sponsoredProducts",
    "metrics": ",".join([
        "adGroupId",
        "adGroupName",
        "asin",
        "attributedSales14dOtherSKU",
        "attributedSales1dOtherSKU",
        "attributedSales30dOtherSKU",
        "attributedSales7dOtherSKU",
        "attributedUnitsOrdered14d",
        "attributedUnitsOrdered14dOtherSKU",
        "attributedUnitsOrdered1d",
        "attributedUnitsOrdered1dOtherSKU",
        "attributedUnitsOrdered30d",
        "attributedUnitsOrdered30dOtherSKU",
        "attributedUnitsOrdered7d",
        "attributedUnitsOrdered7dOtherSKU",
        "campaignId",
        "campaignName",
        "currency",
        "keywordText",
        "matchType",
        "otherAsin",
        "targetingExpression",
        "targetingType"

    ])
```

The creation of the report returns this,

```
{'recordType': 'otherAsin',
 'reportId': 'report_id',
 'status': 'IN_PROGRESS',
 'statusDetails': 'Report is being generated.'}
```

Get request for the report data returns,

```
{'expiration': 1654041600000,
 'fileSize': 22,
 'location': 'https://advertising-api-eu.amazon.com/v1/reports/report_id/download',
 'reportId': 'report_id',
 'status': 'SUCCESS',
 'statusDetails': 'Report has been successfully generated.'}
```

but when calling the location link and as well as trying with the V2 link which is
"https://advertising-api-eu.amazon.com/v2/reports/report_id/download",
I get back an empty list like this,

```
[]
```

There should be data for the date as well, any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out, there is a conflict for some reason, if I put both "**asin**" and "**otherAsin**" in the asins_json_data dictionary. It has to be either one of them in the metrics.
According to the [official document](https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/reference/1/reports) it should not happen. But it also depends on the campaign itself, if they contain the attributes, they should not conflict, vice versa otherwise.